# InAppBilling: PURCHASE_STATE_CHANGED message sometimes do not received

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I have implemented InAppBilling in my application and after publication I have found that *sometimes* my application did not received PURCHASE_STATE_CHANGED message and onPurchaseStateChange is never called. Sometimes it takes hours to receive it.

I know that it is known issues https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/RoAEFI8-NBs

On the other hand it always received REQUEST_PURCHASE message with correct information about purchace state (if user card is invalid).

The questions are:

1. Could I use REQUEST_PURCHASE message as final information about purchace transaction and perform all operation in onRequestPurchaseResponse callback?
2. If it is incorrect please tell me - what is the best way to act in such situation? May be someone already find a good solution?

Thank you in advance,
Tina